# Moving text messages from 2.2 to 4.2

Tags: sms, backup, lg-optimus-one, lg-optimus-l90

I had recently purchased new LG Optimus L90 (model D415, Android 4.2.2, default OEM set up, Optimus UI) to replace old Optimus T (Optimus One, P509, 2.2). I had used SMS Backup+ to move my messages, call logs etc. I had successfully used it before when I did factory reset on the old mobile.

When I installed SMS Backup+ on the new phone, it did copy call logs, and it seemed to copy messages as well, because when I would tap the message icon for the first few times, it would flash old messages for a fraction of a second, but then would only display the new ones. I tried reboot the phone, and checked the settings, but nothing helped.

Is there a way to make this work, or should I try another app?

*Update:* I had tried restoring the messages again today, and when I check the list while SMS Backup+ is running I can see it populating with contacts that I had exchanged messages with. But if I click on any of them there are no messages inside, and so the app thinks of those as deleted and clears them upon list refresh.